# How to make NSFilehandle to delete and write data concurrently in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety, nsfilehandle

I have written 2 methods:

1. WriteToLogFile
2. DeleteLogFile

and I am using `NSFileHandle` for this

My Code is written as:

```
- (void)WriteToLogFile:(NSString *)string {

 dispatch_async(logQueue ,^ {
        if (nil == fileHandle) {
            // log file not opened
            NSLog(@"LogFile not opened");
            return;
        }
        [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [fileHandle writeData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
      });
    }
```

And other function to delete as:

```
-(void) deleteLogDataFromFile
{
    NSString *logFilePath = [self getLogFilePath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:logFilePath])
    {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:logFilePath contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];
    fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:logFilePath];
    }
}
```

Now I am calling these 2 methods  from a loop to check if it crashes at some point where it fileHandle will try to Write to file and will found no such file exist

```
for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
    [self WriteToLogFile:@"Hello"];
    [self DeleteLogs];
}
```

And Xcode throws me error b/w loop is running

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSFileHandleOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:]: Bad file descriptor'

So I need to know how should I make my Write to file Or Delete to file work together , I know I should do some locking on fileHandle.
Can anyone tell what should be done in order to fix this  issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `dispatch_async(logQueue ,^ {...});` in deleteLogDataFromFile method should do the trick. (assuming logQueue s a serial dispatch queue).

For additional safety, consider making fileHandle a property in the class. Then override the getter, use

```
@ synchronized(_fileHandle){
    return _fileHandle
}
```

And finally, use self.fileHandle in WriteToLogFile method.

Comment: Thanks mehul for the suggesttion
using same logQueue works good. but only thing is its now have bcome more time consuming .anyways i will accept your solution.

Comment: thats because all your tasks are now lined up within the same serial dispatch queue... I am not really sure as to what exactly are you trying to achieve/prove with the above code, but one solution could be to dispatch_async on system concurrent queues, and have semaphores (dispatch_semaphore_t) across the critical fileHandle code.